# Check JS variable for both not null and true

Tags: javascript, variables

What is the best way to check if a javascript variable is both not null and true?

So for example, let’s say I have the below code:

```
var trueVar = true; 
var falseVar = false; 

function checkNotNullAndTrue(someVar) {
    if (someVar != null && someVar) {
        return 1; 
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

checkNotNullAndTrue(trueVar) should return 1.

checkNotNullAndTrue(falseVar) should return 0.

checkNotNullAndTrue(someUndefinedVariable) should also return 0.

Is this the best way to do this or is there a better way?

Comment: use `+!!` operator like this `+!!varname` (it is three operators actually,`+`, `!`, `!`)

Comment: @BryanChen That is not cryptic enough. I am sure you can do better.

Comment: @BryanChen first time for me see such a thing... thanks!

Comment: If it's truthy (including `true`), it can't be `null`.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen you need the `===+!!([!![]]+[])` synthetic operator if you want to just get `true` and not merely truthy. (Added this to my answer.)

Comment: @djechlin I was thinking about getting a Perl guy in here to help, but I see you have it under control.

Comment: @djechlin I think "not cryptic enough" was sarcasm. The readable version of `+!!x` would be `Number(Boolean(x))`

Comment: @Oriol https://jsfiddle.net/01yzb11p/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kind of a weird question since `null` is falsy.

```
return x === true; // not null and 'true';
return x; // return truthy value if x not null and truthy; falsy otherwise
return !!x; // return true if x not null and truthy, false otherwise
return +!!x; // return 1 if x not null and truthy, 0 otherwise
```

`!!x` is same as `!(!x)` and casts `x` to true or false *and* negates, then negates a second time. Either a hack or a pattern that is same as `Boolean(x)` depending on your worldview.

`+<boolean>` will cast convert the boolean to the number 1 or 0.

Anyway someone requested a cryptic answer and "true" uses a lot of unnecessary characters so here it is:

```
return +!!(x === ([!![]]+[])); // 1 if x not null and true; 0 otherwise
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply with the [strict equality operator (`===`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity_strict_equality_()):

> The identity operator returns `true` if the operands are strictly equal [...] with no type conversion.

```
function checkNotNullAndTrue(v) {
    return v === true ? 1 : 0;
}
```

or

```
function checkNotNullAndTrue(v) {
    return +(v === true);
}
```

Why hacky stuff does not work, sometimes:

```js
// djechlin's part
write(+!!1);                           // 1 obviously not true
write(+!![]);                          // 1 obviously not true

// quentin's part
function test (valid_variable_name) {
    if (valid_variable_name) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

write(test(1));                        // 1 obviously not true
write(test([]));                       // 1 obviously not true

// my part
var v = true;
write(+(v === true));                  // 1 true (the only one, that would work!)
write(+(1 === true));                  // 0 false, works
write(+([] === true));                 // 0 false, works


function write(x) {
    document.write(x + '<br>');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `null` (and `undefined`, which you mention in your examples) are not  true values, testing for them is redundant.

```
if (valid_variable_name) {
    return 1;
}
return 0;
```

… is sufficient.

… or `if (valid_variable_name === true)` if you want to test for `true` rather than any true value.

Comment: but on 1, you get 1 (`true`), it should return 0 (`false`).